# Facebook graph api - check what applications my friends are using

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to build a facebook app that will serve as a portal for all the apps I am using and the apps my friends are using.

A user could come in, see a thumbnail image if each application he and his friends are using and be able to go to the application from within the portal.

I've been looking through Facebook graph api, and I cannot figure how this can be done. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot get list of applications user is using or check whenever user is using specific application other than your own.